# Why is NHibernate generating schema with the class name as a column?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to generate my database from classes using NHibernate, but the schema that's being created contains a column for the class. For the most part this wouldn't matter but one class in particular is causing this to fail... my Order class (because order is a reserved keyword in SQL - yes maybe I should have used a word that wasn't a keyword but that's another issue)

The following mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<class name="Order" table="Orders">
    <id name="_persistenceID" column="ID" type="Guid" access="field" unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
        <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <version name="_persistenceVersion" column="Version" access="field" type="int" unsaved-value="0" />

    <property name="DateDeleted" column="DateDeleted" type="DateTime" />
    <property name="ChangeReason" column="ChangeReason" type="String" not-null="true" />
    <property name="CompletedDate" column="CompletedDate" type="DateTime" />
    <property name="IsDeleted" column="IsDeleted" type="Boolean" />
    <property name="Notes" column="Notes" type="String" />
    <property name="OrderDate" column="OrderDate" type="DateTime" not-null="true" />
    <property name="OrderTotal" column="OrderTotal" type="Decimal" />
    <property name="RequiredDate" column="RequiredDate" type="DateTime" />

    <many-to-one name="Customer" column="Customer" class="Customer" not-null="true" />

    <bag name="OrderDetails" table="OrderDetails" generic="true" cascade="all">
        <key column="OrderDetail" foreign-key="FK_OrderOrderDetails" />
        <one-to-many class="OrderDetail" />
    </bag>

</class>
```

produces the following SQL:

```
    create table Orders (
  ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
   Version INT not null,
   DateDeleted DATETIME null,
   ChangeReason NVARCHAR(255) not null,
   CompletedDate DATETIME null,
   IsDeleted BIT null,
   Notes NVARCHAR(255) null,
   OrderDate DATETIME not null,
   OrderTotal DECIMAL(19,5) null,
   RequiredDate DATETIME null,
   Customer UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
   Order UNIQUEIDENTIFIER null,
   primary key (ID)
)
```

It's that 2nd to last column (Order) that's causing this to be invalid and highlighted the issue. It is happening on all my other classes - but I've no idea why. What can I do about it?

Edit: 30/11/2010 - The other end of the mapping file:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="TheWorkshop.DomainModel" namespace="TheWorkshop.DomainModel" default-access="field.camelcase-underscore" default-lazy="true">

<class name="OrderDetail" table="OrderDetails">
    <id name="_persistenceID" column="ID" type="Guid" access="field" unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
        <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <version name="_persistenceVersion" column="Version" access="field" type="int" unsaved-value="0" />

    <property name="AdjustedPrice" column="AdjustedPrice" type="Decimal" not-null="true" />
    <property name="LineCost" column="LineCost" type="Decimal" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Notes" column="Notes" type="String" />
    <property name="Photo" column="Photo" type="String" />
    <property name="Price" column="Price" type="Decimal" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Quantity" column="Quantity" type="int" />

    <many-to-one name="`Order`" column="`Order`" class="Order" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="Product" column="Product" class="Product" not-null="true" />

</class>
```

and that generates the following:

```
create table OrderDetails (
ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
Version INT not null,
AdjustedPrice DECIMAL(19,5) not null,
LineCost DECIMAL(19,5) not null,
Notes NVARCHAR(255) null,
Photo NVARCHAR(255) null,
Price DECIMAL(19,5) not null,
Quantity INT null,
[Order] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
Product UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
primary key (ID)
)
```

Comment: Which version of NH are you using? Your hbm.xml files looks fine. Somehow it appears to be trying to create an Order column as the PK in addition to ID as a separate column. When I run this hbm.xml file using NH3, it correctly specifies ID as the PK and no Order column. Have you tried running just this hbm.xml file separately? What does your Order class look like. (BTW - If property name == column, you don't have to specify column. Also data types can usually be inferred. So you can omit them in most cases.)

Comment: I'm using NH2.1.1.GA
I have tried running the hbm with just the id and it still throws the error, trying to add the Order column. It's the same for all my other entites - for example this is generated for OrderDetail:
create table OrderDetails (
  ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
   Version INT not null,
   AdjustedPrice DECIMAL(19,5) not null,
   LineCost DECIMAL(19,5) not null,
   Price DECIMAL(19,5) not null,
   Quantity INT null,
   [Order] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
   Product UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
   OrderDetail UNIQUEIDENTIFIER null,
   primary key (ID)
)

Comment: I _could_ try running NH 3, but didn't think it was fully released yet? 
Most of my property names == column names - I could make the hbm more readable, thanks for the tip :)

If the hbm generates the correct schema for you... what could be causing it to generate the funky schema I'm getting?

Comment: I've used SchemaExport in NH2.x projects too without problem, though generally I have a PK of "public Guid Id { get; private set; }" or similar. That shouldn't make any difference. NH3 will be released very shortly. I would give it a try even if only to rule out a bug with NH2.x. Looking over the release notes for NH3, I don't see any fixes that would resolve your issue. There is a fix for quoting tables/columns that are also SQL keywords, but honestly that column name shouldn't be generated at all.

Comment: I'm using a base class for my domain entities that provides a protected _persistenceID, which I think is similar to what you're suggesting. Is there any way to fathom out what's causing the extra column?

Comment: Actually, I said I _could_ try NH3 but I'm also using Rhino.Commons.NHibernate and suspect I'd run into issues if I updated? This is my 1st NH project, so apologies if I'm not missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the key column is set to OrderDetail. The column attribute should contain the name of the foreign key column from the Order table in OrderDetail and I doubt you've named that column OrderDetail. My guess is that it should be OrderID. It may be a bug in schema generation that occurs when a class name is supplied instead of the column name.

```
<key column="OrderDetail" foreign-key="FK_OrderOrderDetails" />
```

Comment: I tried renaming the column to `Order` as it is in my OrderDetails.hbm.xml file (see the edit above), but it didn't change things. I went with OrderDetails as I wanted to be able to refer to Orders.OrderDetails.xxx rather than Orders.OrderID.xxx - but if that's not the way to do things I'm more than happy to change. Interestingly the generated schema does not even mention OrderDetails.

Comment: The key column represents the foreign key name in the OrderDetails table; the bag name represents the collection property in your class. The schema for Orders should not contain any reference to OrderDetails. When you changed the column to Order, the generated schema was identical to the original version? Your naming convention is making this a little hard to follow.

Comment: I want to be able to go from Orders to OrderDetails to see all the records that make up an order. I also want to be able to go from OrderDetails to an Order - an order can have many orderdetails and an orderdetail belongs to an order. This is very much my 1st NH project so if I've got things wrong please suggest a better way.